# How to send data from client's html to node.js server?

Tags: node.js, html

I wanted to send JSON data to node.js server.

This is my server.js :

```
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util')
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

console.log('Request received: ');
util.log(util.inspect(req)) // this line helps you inspect the request so you can see whether the data is in the url (GET) or the req body (POST)
util.log('Request recieved: \nmethod: ' + req.method + '\nurl: ' + req.url) // this line logs just the method and url

res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain','Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('GOT DATA!');
});
res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');

}).listen(8090);
console.log('Server running on port 8090');
```

This is html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js "></script>
</head>

<body>
response here: <p id="lblResponse">fill me in</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/',
    // dataType: "jsonp",
    data:   '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null },
    type: 'POST',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback', // this is not relevant to the POST   anymore
    success: function (data) {
        var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#lblResponse').html(ret.msg);
        console.log('Success: ')
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
        $('#lblResponse').html('Error connecting to the server.');

    },
});
 });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
"VM162:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Function.parseJSON (jquery-1.8.3.js:514)
at Object.success (file:///home/techm/Desktop/test%20(server-client)/client.html:20:30)
at fire (jquery-1.8.3.js:974)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.8.3.js:1084)
at done (jquery-1.8.3.js:7803)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.8.3.js:8518)
```

I don't why I am getting this error because I am little new to node.js server. And if I get the data I want to save it in a local file.

Comment: Seems you have some malformed JSON.  What does your JSON look like?

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is JSON data I wanted to send : '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }

Comment: Seems legit.  So why is JSON.parse seeing the character 'c' at the very first position in your JSON string?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's my question :-) why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax request should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/',
    data: { "name": "John", "age":30, "car":null },
    type: 'POST'
    .....
})
```

And in createServer method of server.js update this

```
if (req.method == 'POST') {
    console.log("POST");
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
        console.log("Partial body: " + body);
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Body: " + body);
    });
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');
}
else
{
    console.log("GET");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');
}
```

Comment: Explain why this works, and why the OP's code doesn't.

Comment: @Sanjaysinh It's happening thanks for your quick solution. Now how can I save JSON data to local file?

Comment: I added 'let data1 = JSON.stringify(body);
    fs.writeFileSync('text.json',data1);' But it's copying only " " in json file