# Pass a Variable from html to server

Tags: html, node.js, variables

I created an simple node.js application to improve my skills. 
I declared a variable in xxxx.html:

```
  var value = document.getElementById('codeTextbox').value;
```

When I try to pass the value to my app.js I always get an undefined error.
Do you know how I can handle this?

My folderstrucure: Projekt > App.js and publicfolder. And public contains xxxx.html

Comment: on what action you are passing that value?

Comment: to: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/'+ value)));

Comment: here you are concating the value not getting the value from html is there a function when you are getting the value from html?

Comment: Oh. No I dont have a function. Thats what I am needing. Because I dont know how to get the value from html

Comment: you can get there are alot of example here on stack of How to post data from html to node

Comment: I tried to get a example here, but I can not find one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033050/11046080